# How to use crc32 function in hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, crc32

I am a newbie to hive and exploring collections and hashing.
I came across the crc32 function in HiveUDF page, but when trying to query it , it returns me a "invalid function" error.

Any pointers?

I have previously implemented crc32 in java and am completely aware of hashing concepts and usage. This is more in regards to whether hive has an inbuilt crc32 function and how to use it in a hive query.

Regards,

Comment: What version of Hive? What kind of data (datatype) to hash? What kind of error -- at query compile time, or at execution time?

Comment: I am using hive version 2.4.2.0-258, and the error that I am getting is FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10011]: Line 1:7 Invalid function 'crc32'

Comment: I am converting string to hash

Comment: HIve Version: Hive 1.2.1000.2.4.2.0-258

Comment: crc32 added in Hive 1.3.0:  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-Misc.Functions

Comment: Ah ok..I am able to use sha256 like this tho. `SELECT reflect('org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils', 'sha256Hex','<string>') from some_table;`  Any idea if it might be possible to  use crc32 in the same way.

Comment: No, AFAIK -- most hash functions require multiple lines of code to initialize, ingest bytes *(yeah, bytes, not strings that use platform-dependent encoding e.g. UTF-16 or UTF-8 depending on the JDK)*, finalize, and convert the bytes to RAW or STRING.

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
crc32(your_column_name)
```